# How to set the keybinding for addind the hash symbol (#) in spacemacs with MacOS and an UK keyboard

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, osx, keymap

I'm using spacemacs on a Mac OS X laptop with a UK keyboard and I want to be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> (`M-3`) to insert the hash symbol `#`. I tried to add this function that I found on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786456/1977778) without any luck.

```
;; Allow hash to be entered  
(global-set-key (kbd "M-3") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "#")))
```

Do I have to `unset` this key combination before trying to set it? Is there anything else in the **spacemacs** configuration that always overwrite my user defined configuration with the *"Change the current window with window 3"*?
I'm used to add the hash symbol using that combination and I feel uncomfortable using anything else.

Comment: Rather than dealing with that issue on Emacs, I added the Australian keyboard on my Mac, so # was S-3 and then didn't change anything to the Emacs config.

Comment: I can't change my MacBook integrated keyboard. So this is not a viable solution to my problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain myself correctly. Not the physical keyboard. You can change it on the settings panel (you can have multiple layouts and change them in the fly). There are barely differences between the uk and aus layout, so having still the uk physical keyboard is barely noticeable

Comment: Actually as I wrote in the question itself I feel uncomfortable using something else than <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>, so I was looking for the correct way to configure Spacemacs to accept this custom keybinding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach is set `(setq-default mac-right-option-modifier nil)` to your `dotspacemacs/user-init` and start to use the "**right Option+3**" key to write the '#' symbol.

Definition:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
  (setq-default mac-right-option-modifier nil)
)
```

Comment: Cheers @Joao. This approach is working and it solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I setup my `init.el`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-3") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "#")))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "~")))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-g") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "@")))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-7") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "|")))
```